# Error during install of vCenter on ESXi(which is installed on PC)

Tags: linux, vmware, esxi, vmware-workstation, vcenter

For 4 days I've been trying to deploy a home virtual environment for test purposes. I'm relatively new in vCenter deployment.

I have a laptop which has 8GB RAM. I know that the RAM is not enough but I'm sure that there is a way to implement a small environment. Also, I know that the minimum requirement to deploy vCenter is 12GB RAM, but I changed the resource file and entered '2048'MB as a minimum and this allows me to continue with the installation of the center.

I successfully installed VMware ESXi 6.7 on VMware Workstation Pro 16.
Afterward, I started to install vCenter 6.7 on my ESXi. I entered the right settings(it's important to note that I don't have a DNS server. Instead of DNS, I entered the IP of my default Gateway. I have logged in the vCenter machine via SSH and I can ping the Gateway)

Stage 1 of the installing vCenter finished successfully, but on the second stage2, I have got an error.

The error is the following:
[image]

I checked the logs and I saw this:
[image]

After clicking on retry it won't let me to continue the installation(I have got the same error window).

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are at this step all requirement are met.

If you don't have DNS server you have to use an IP address for the name when  configuring your vCenter.